# Иерархия папок. Скорость доступа в ext4

Tags: архитектура, файловая-система, ext4

Нужно создавать папку для каждого юзера. У юзера будет ид (32байта -строка 64 символа). Соответственно как быстро будет поисходить доступ по storage/5A64/C5CC/... Тоесть 16 уровней папок по 2 байта на уровень ?

Comment: что значит «как быстро»? Достаточно быстро, чтобы единичный доступ к произвольной папке был не заметен, быстрее, чем если все папки свалить в кучу, но медленнее, чем если бы данные вместо папок лежали бы в базе данных с индексами по имени...

Comment: Проблема в том что данные не просто статические бинарники например картинки, а бинарники по которым происходит seek и прочие манипуляции, в базу или nosql закатать не получится.

Comment: Как у вас из строки из 64 символов получилось 16 уровней папок?

Comment: Для ФС общего назначения лучшая сложность будет O(sqrt(N)), для 128 уровней с семибитными папками ([0-8][0-F]), правда боюсь по факту тут уже на системных вызовах и фрагментированном дисковом вводе/выводе начнёт тормозить. К O(log(N)) приблизится ни как не получится... попробовать конечно можно, но ИМХО тут стоит поискать что-то более специализированное... Если искать ФС, то по факту единственное требование — индексы по именам каталогов... ЕМНИП где-то я такое видел...

Comment: А видел я это, судя по всему, в JFS. Не буду рекомендовать использовать, но попробовать ИМХО стоит... В теории, тут как раз будет эффективней свалить все каталоги в кучу.

Comment: И тоже самое касается XFS.